# Firebase App Check on Flutter Web Debug mode crash with [firebase_auth/network-request-failed]

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I get this weird err on Flutter Web with AppCheck on Debug mode:

> [firebase_auth/network-request-failed] A network AuthError (such as
> timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

I have to say this err doesn't occur if I release this app (no debug mode).

So im doing these steps

1. The web app is register
2. Auth Storage and Firebase are enforced
3. reCAPTCHA type:v3 keys for my web app, with correct domain
4. keys added correctly into my web app in AppCheck
5. Debug Token added in my web app in AppCheck, when running on localhost:5000

Is this a firebase app check bug? If released app works is there something wrong I do maybe?